# Gatsby bundles failed

Tags: css, gatsby, netlify

Node 12
Running `Gatbsy build`

Errors I get

```
 ERROR #98123  WEBPACK

Generating JavaScript bundles failed

Module parse failed: Unexpected character '' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
(Source code omitted for this binary file)

File: src/styles/plugins/rs-plugin-6.custom/css/rs6.css:1:0


 ERROR #98123  WEBPACK

Generating JavaScript bundles failed

Unexpected character '' (1:0)

File: src/styles/plugins/rs-plugin-6.custom/css/openhand.cur:1:0
```

I tracked the error down to this the css file and this line.

```
rs-carousel-wrap {
    cursor:url(openhand.cur), move;
}
```

Is there something I need to import to be able to get it to recognize this css in gatsby?

Comment: Can you provide more details about the error? Only seeing the output it's impossible to guess where the issue comes from. What's `r6.css`? How is your webpack configuration?

Comment: Thanks for your response.  rs6.css is a css file that came with a package I'm attempting to configure into gatsby.  @FerranBuireu

Comment: Can you share it? It seems that is there something odd there.

Comment: I pinpointed the error to exactly this line in a css file: rs-carousel-wrap {
 cursor:url(openhand.cur), move;
}. @FerranBuireu

Comment: Have you tried using relative paths? `cursor:URL("./openhand.cur"), move;`
`

Comment: It worked, thank you! @FerranBuireu

Comment: I'm glad to help @FabricioG , I've added an answer for you to accept in order to close the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my comments with [@FabricioG](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2690257/fabriciog), the issue has been solved using relative paths, after some research in the project structure.

This does the trick:

```
cursor:URL("./openhand.cur"), move;
```